# My sidebar is not getting the widget content in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, sidebar

It's not getting the widget value and I created this sidebar, but I don't know why it's not getting the widget on wordpress, Could be some code overwrite?.

[image]

Comment: where you have registered the sidebar ? can you show that code ?

Comment: first thing first, check whether sidebar-facebook.php is getting called or not. Print any extra text there. If it is calling remove is_active_sidebar condition and check once.

Comment: I updated the drive link and still not working the widget

Comment: I tried to tell you to write that text in sidebar-facebook.php itself not in page110.php

Comment: see you sidebar-facebook.php is not getting called at all

Comment: So where ebver you have putted calling the sidebar code get side bar... replace that code with dynamic_sidebar function directly. It will work.

Comment: It worked thank you very much. If you need help help in something. You can talk to me. 

https://www.linkedin.com/in/marcelo-apovian-kayata-33570778/

I am new in stackoverflow I don't know if someone can ask help directly to a person.

Comment: It is always pleasing to know everything is working fine ;)